# Type Clipboard has no member 'objects' in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass an array `objects` to another view and i'm getting the following error:

> Type Clipboard has no member `objects`

this is the code I'm using to pass it:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    var Clipboard = segue.destinationViewController as! ClipBoard
    var selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    ClipBoard.objects = objects[selectedIndexPath.row]
}
```

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm using "self" with objects just before hand to pull from `CloudKit`.

Comment: I'm sending from tableview UITableViewController 'CopyList' to UITableViewController 'Clipboard'

Comment: Can you post code of your `ClipBoard` class please?

Comment: `
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class ClipBoard: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ClipBoardText: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var SaveButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
         self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = SaveButton
    }
    

    @IBAction func Save(sender: AnyObject) {
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}`

Comment: Where is the property `objects` in class `ClipBoard`? That's the reason of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not use variable names with the same name as the type.**

Declare always variables starting with a lowercase letter to avoid that confusion.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)

{
    var clipboard = segue.destinationViewController as! ClipBoard
    var selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    clipboard.objects = objects[selectedIndexPath.row]
}
```

**Edit:** And there is a typo : `ClipBoard` vs. `Clipboard`

Comment: Is the class of your destination view controller set to `ClipBoard` in Interface Builder? I assume it really has a property `objects.`

Comment: it is set to this, but im not sure if it has property object.s where can I set this?

Comment: Declare it in class `Clipboard`. You'll probably need it. And it's supposed to be singular because you save one object from the `objects` array

Comment: How can I declare it  please?

Comment: I have no idea what the type of `objects` in the first view controller is. The type to be declared is the type of the items in the array.

Comment: Ok, I feel a bit lost now....

Objects is declared as the following:

var objects = [CKRecord]()

which gets filled with a string form icloud:

  privateDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (records, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog("Error performing query. \(error.debugDescription)")
                return
            }
        
            self.objects = records!
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

Comment: There are lots of examples here on SO how to pass parameters to a destination view controller and how to handle the parameters there.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you created a variable with the same name os your class. 
When you do this:
`ClipBoard.objects = objects[selectedIndexPath.row]`

The compiler thinks that you are setting a value to a static variable in your class called ClipBoard.

The solution is to change the variable name to lowercase 'c'. Ex.: clipBoard